# calculate profit distribution ranges

Tags: php, math

I'm looking for a math formula.

Let's suppose we have these 3 variables:

```
Sales: 45000
Cost: 20000
Profit: 25000
```

Now I need to distribute profit on some ranges:

```
Range 1 from 0 to 30000 on sales -> profit will be 10000 
Range 2 from 30001 to 40000 on sales -> profit will be 10000
Range 3 from 40001 to 50000 on sales -> profit will be 5000

The profit sum of those ranges will be: 25000
```

The profit distribution in the first range is 10000, in the second another 10000 and in the third range will be 5000. That is the relation I need to get.

I need to find how to relate this in PHP, entering sales, cost and profit and in some how to calculate those profit ranges.

Graphic explanation:
[image: table]

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how if works. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: @timclutton I have tried on paper all types of relations between those numbers but no clue in how is that relation made. My client has that structure but I cant figure it out.

Comment: @Andreas I thought I know how to use if, but I have no clue in dividing that total profit in those ranges, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved, I think it would be a better way or some formula to solve this, but here is my approach:

```
    $totalExpenses = 45000;
    $income = 20000;
    $distribution = $income - $totalExpenses;


    if ($income >= 0 && $income <= 30000){

        $max1 = $income;
        $range1 = $max1 - $totalExpenses;

        echo "r1: ".$range1;

    }

    if ($income >= 30001 && $income <= 40000){

        $max1 = 30000;
        $range1 = $max1 - $totalExpenses;

        $max2 = $income;
        $range2 = $max2 - $totalExpenses - $range1;


        echo "r1: ".$range1." r2: ".$range2;

    }

    if ($income >= 40001 && $income <= 50000){

        $max1 = 30000;
        $range1 = $max1 - $totalExpenses;

        $max2 = 40000;
        $range2 = $max2 - $totalExpenses - $range1;

        $max3 = $income;
        $range3 = $max3 - $totalExpenses - $range1 - $range2;


        echo "r1: ".$range1." r2: ".$range2." r3: ".$range3;

    }
```

This example will output the three ranges we are looking for:

```
Range1: 10000
Range2: 10000
Range3: 5000 

Total 25000 profit
```

Answer (score -1):

make a html/php form to enter sales, cost and after submit calculate profit
check this profit in switch statement or if else statement
use following or similar php code

```
if ($sales > 0 and $sales <= 30000)
{
    $profit=10000;
}
else
{
    if ($sales >= 30001 and $sales <= 40000)
    {
        $profit=10000;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($sales >= 40001 and $sales <= 50000)
        {
            $profit=5000;
        }
    }
}
```

you have to define one total variable and above part in while loop and take total of profit to total variable and after end of loop print echo that total variable

you can get as many as values you want in while loop not only three

Comment: I have the php form and those variables, $cost $sales $profit already but how that switch / if will be structured? that is my problem, I'm stuck

Comment: this is defining the profit variable, and I need to calculate it in each case, to finally sum the three cases and get the original 25000 profit value

Comment: I need to calculate the tree ranges for a given profit number, suppose 25000, I need to get the tree profit sales range value.